# How to untar a file second time using file spec explode:true on a Jenkins job

Tags: artifactory

I'm using file spec below in a Jenkins job to download artifact and untar the artifact. It untar it but that tar has 2 other tar files and I need to untar those 2 files as well. How can I do that using explode:true the second time?

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "sys /${RELEASE}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/samples*.tar.gz",
            "target": "${PATH}",
            "explode": true,
            "target": " server.tar.gz",
            "explode": true
        }
    ]
```

Comment: explode: true works for untaring.

Comment: Unfortunately - this feature is currently not supported. However, you can untar using Groovy dsl or shell commands.

Comment: thanks @yahavi will try to use Groovy dsl.